# Unable to configure Sonarcube with Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, sonarqube, devops, ojdbc

I have downloaded community version of sonarcube on my local

When I am trying to run it throws me error

**Error **

`C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar
Starting SonarQube...
2024.03.10 18:09:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\temp
2024.03.10 18:09:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:54083]
2024.03.10 18:09:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java -Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dcli.name=server -Dcli.script=./bin/elasticsearch -Dcli.libs=lib/tools/server-cli -Des.path.home=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\temp\conf\es -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\elasticsearch\lib*;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\elasticsearch\lib\cli-launcher* org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
2024.03.10 18:09:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
Mar 10, 2024 6:09:44 PM sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter 
WARNING: COMPAT locale provider will be removed in a future release
2024.03.10 18:10:01 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2024.03.10 18:10:01 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[WEB_SERVER] from [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dcom.redhat.fips=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/sonar-application-10.4.1.88267.jar;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\extensions\jdbc-driver\oracle\ojdbc8.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\temp\sq-process3052836980689939236properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:429)
at org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager.restrictPlugins(PluginSecurityManager.java:42)
at org.sonar.server.app.WebSecurityManager.apply(WebSecurityManager.java:47)
at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:101)
2024.03.10 18:10:03 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [Web Server]: 1
2024.03.10 18:10:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[Web Server] is stopped
2024.03.10 18:10:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2024.03.10 18:10:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DevOps\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\bin\windows-x86-64>`

Following is the Sonarcube properties changed

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# IMPORTANT:
# This file will *not* be reloaded upon hitting the "Restart" button in the UI, or using the
# api/system/restart endpoint.
# In order for any change made to this file to be taken into account, you must perform a full
# restart of the main SonarQube service.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Property values can:
# - be overridden by environment variables. The name of the corresponding environment variable is the
#   upper-cased name of the property where all the dot ('.') and dash ('-') characters are replaced by
#   underscores ('_'). For example, to override 'sonar.web.systemPasscode' use 'SONAR_WEB_SYSTEMPASSCODE'.
# - be encrypted. See https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/instance-administration/security/#settings-encryption

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT:
# - The embedded H2 database is used by default. It is recommended for tests but not for
#   production use. Supported databases are Oracle, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQLServer.
# - Changes to database connection URL (sonar.jdbc.url) can affect SonarSource licensed products.

# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username=dev
sonar.jdbc.password=dev

#----- Embedded Database (default)
# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9092


#----- Oracle 19c/21c
# The Oracle JDBC driver must be copied into the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/.
# Only the thin client is supported, and we recommend using the latest Oracle JDBC driver. See
# https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9758 for more details.
# If you need to set the schema, please refer to http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:dev@localhost:1521/ORCL
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:dev/dev@//localhost:1521/ORCL
#dev@//localhost:1521/ORCL


#----- PostgreSQL 11 or greater
# By default the schema named "public" is used. It can be overridden with the parameter "currentSchema".
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube?currentSchema=my_schema


#----- Microsoft SQLServer 2014/2016/2017/2019/2022 and SQL Azure
# A database named sonar must exist and its collation must be case-sensitive (CS) and accent-sensitive (AS)
# Use the following connection string if you want to use integrated security with Microsoft Sql Server
# Do not set sonar.jdbc.username or sonar.jdbc.password property if you are using Integrated Security
# For Integrated Security to work, you have to download the Microsoft SQL JDBC Auth 12.4.2 package from
# https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases/download/v12.4.2/mssql-jdbc_auth.zip
# and 'mssql-jdbc_auth-12.4.2.x64.dll' to your path.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=true

# Use the following connection string if you want to use SQL Auth while connecting to MS Sql Server.
# Set the sonar.jdbc.username and sonar.jdbc.password appropriately.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sonar


#----- Connection pool settings
# The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated
# at the same time, or negative for no limit.
# The recommended value is 1.2 * max sizes of HTTP pools. For example if HTTP ports are
# enabled with default sizes (50, see property sonar.web.http.maxThreads)
# then sonar.jdbc.maxActive should be 1.2 * 50 = 60.
#sonar.jdbc.maxActive=60

# The minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool,
# without extra ones being created, or zero to create none.
#sonar.jdbc.minIdle=10

# The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there
# are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before
# throwing an exception, or <= 0 to wait indefinitely.
#sonar.jdbc.maxWait=8000


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER
# Web server is executed in a dedicated Java process. By default heap size is 512MB.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options.
#    Recommendations:
#
#    The HotSpot Server VM is recommended. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment:
#    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#    Startup can be long if entropy source is short of entropy. Adding
#    -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom is an option to resolve the problem.
#    See https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Entropy_Source
#
#sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
#sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# Changing this value and restarting the server can have unexpected consequences for logged in users,
# as they may end up with multiple conflicting browser cookies. If your users experience odd
# behaviors after you changed this value and restarted the server, ask them to clear their browser's
# cookies and log in again.
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
sonar.web.port=9000


# The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
# When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until
# the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections
# based on the sonar.web.connections.acceptCount property. The default value is 50.
#sonar.web.http.maxThreads=50

# The minimum number of threads always kept running. The default value is 5.
#sonar.web.http.minThreads=5

# The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing
# threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.
# The default value is 25.
#sonar.web.http.acceptCount=25

# The number of milliseconds this Connector will wait for another HTTP request before closing the
# connection. The default value is to use the value that has been set for the connectionTimeout 
# attribute. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout.
# The default value is 60000 (ms).
#sonar.web.http.keepAliveTimeout=60000

# By default users are logged out and sessions closed when server is restarted.
# If you prefer keeping user sessions open, a secret should be defined. Value is
# HS256 key encoded with base64. It must be unique for each installation of SonarQube.
# Example of command-line:
# echo -n "type_what_you_want" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "key" -binary | base64
#sonar.auth.jwtBase64Hs256Secret=

# The inactivity timeout duration of user sessions, in minutes. After the configured
# period of time, the user is logged out.
# The default value is set to 3 days (4320 minutes).
# It must be set between 6 minutes and 3 months (129600 minutes).
# Value must be strictly positive.
#sonar.web.sessionTimeoutInMinutes=4320

# A passcode can be defined to access some web services from monitoring
# tools without having to use the credentials of a system administrator.
# Check the Web API documentation to know which web services are supporting this authentication mode.
# The passcode should be provided in HTTP requests with the header "X-Sonar-Passcode".
# By default feature is disabled.
#sonar.web.systemPasscode=


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SSO AUTHENTICATION

# Enable authentication using HTTP headers
#sonar.web.sso.enable=false

# Name of the header to get the user login.
# Only alphanumeric, '.' and '@' characters are allowed
#sonar.web.sso.loginHeader=X-Forwarded-Login

# Name of the header to get the user name
#sonar.web.sso.nameHeader=X-Forwarded-Name

# Name of the header to get the user email (optional)
#sonar.web.sso.emailHeader=X-Forwarded-Email

# Name of the header to get the list of user groups, separated by comma (optional).
# If the sonar.sso.groupsHeader is set, the user will belong to those groups if groups exist in SonarQube.
# If none of the provided groups exists in SonarQube, the user will only belong to the default group.
# Note that the default group will always be set.
#sonar.web.sso.groupsHeader=X-Forwarded-Groups

# Interval used to know when to refresh name, email and groups.
# During this interval, if for instance the name of the user is changed in the header, it will only be updated after X minutes.
#sonar.web.sso.refreshIntervalInMinutes=5
```

Added jdbc jar file in extension folder :

`ojdbc8.jar`  in folder : `sonarqube-10.4.1.88267\extensions\jdbc-driver\oracle`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C2nr.png)

Could you please help how to configure with Oracle Database

Comment: Looks more like a problem with your Java version that with Oracle connection.

Comment: @p3consulting : Thanks It works with Java 11 and Java 17. I have installed it and it worked.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).